# What is a 'thread-confined' clone?

Tags: java, multithreading

Just what the title states; the term appeared in 'Java Concurrency in Practice'.

I assume it means that a clone may only be created within the thread that holds the lock. Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thread-confined object is one that can only ever be seen by the thread that created it.

So a thread-confined clone of an object is a clone that can only ever be seen by the thread that created it (the clone).

Answer (score 1):

"Since the clone is thread-confined, no other thread can modify it during iteration, eliminating the possibility of ConcurrentModificationException. (The collection still must be locked during the clone operation itself)"

See [this](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/MSC06-J.+Do+not+modify+the+underlying+collection+when+an+iteration+is+in+progress) page.